# http-conduit browser usage

Tags: haskell, https, web-scraping, session-cookies, http-conduit

I'm trying to scrape data from a site using HTTPS. I managed to make basic requests using Network.HTTP.Conduit successfully (posting credentials, etc.), but failed at extracting cookie information from the response headers (Set-Cookie). It looks like http-conduit has its [own mechanism](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.6/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#g:7) for dealing with cookies, which I failed to understand.

Network.HTTP.Conduit.Browser seems to deal with cookies automatically (which is fine by me), but I couldn't get it to work due to lacking [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.6/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit-Browser.html).

Could someone with more experience dealing with the http-conduit browser module show me how to:

1. Deal with self-signed certificates (I managed to do this with [managerCheckCerts](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.6/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:managerCheckCerts) in the base module)
2. Send a POST request with URL-encoded parameters in the body, not following any redirects (I used [urlEncodedBody](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.6/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:urlEncodedBody) from the base module for this)
3. Use the cookie from the 2. step in a simple GET request and read the response as a (lazy) ByteString (I would have used [httpLbs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.2.6/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:httpLbs) for this)

To me it looks like the abstraction level of Network.HTTP.Conduit.Browser is more suited for my application compared to Network.HTTP.Conduit, so I would like to make the switch even if I could deal with cookies manually using the latter.

Comment: I had problem finding documentation too, and it looks like the source code has example code: https://github.com/exbb2/http-conduit-browser/blob/master/Network/HTTP/Conduit/Browser.hs

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Browser, but I have used http-conduit. I read the source code to answer these questions, I apologize if I make any mistakes.

1. Do the same thing you're doing. When you've created the `Manager` with the right `managerCheckCerts`, pass that along to `browse :: Manager -> BrowserAction a -> ResourceT IO a`.
2. `makeRequest :: Request IO -> BrowserAction (Response (Source IO BS.ByteString))` takes a `Request IO`; use `urlEncodedBody` like before to create a POST request with parameters in the body and pass it to `makeRequest`. Set `redirectCount` to 0 to disable redirect following, I believe.
3. I believe you just need to use `getCookieJar       :: BrowserAction CookieJar`; the `BrowserAction` comes from `getBrowserState :: BrowserAction BrowserState`.

The way http-conduit manages cookies outside the Browser module is that it doesn't. Cookies are returned in the HTTP response; what you can do is parse the response and store the cookies in a cookie jar. That's actually all Browser really does.